# Splitting a PDF into PDFs of various sizes

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, documents

I recently upgraded from Adobe Acrobat 6 to 9 and I can't seem to figure outhow to split a large PDF into individual PDFs of various sizes (say, pages 1-3, 4-11, 12, etc.).

I'm aware that A-PDF allows me to pull individual pages form the source document, but I would prefer to set a range & a file-name for each resulting document.

I cannot use an external website for splitting; any suggestions on tools/utilities/whatever I may be missing?

Answer (score 2):

[Sejda PDF](http://sejda.org) is a free open source project that provides PDF manipulation tasks.

It provides a command line tool that you can use to split PDF files by pages:

```
./bin/sejda-console splitbypages --files /input/file.pdf --pageNumbers 4 10 15 -o /output/folder
```

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a command-line utility, [**pdftk**](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) can help.

For example,

```
pdftk Input.pdf cat 1-3 output Pages_1-3.pdf
```

will extract pages 1-3 and save them as Pages_1-3.pdf

If you have a set of page ranges and desired output file names, you can save them to a text file as follows:

```
1-3 Pages_1-3.pdf
4-11 Pages_4-11.pdf
12 Page_12.pdf
13-end Pages_13-end.pdf
```

Now use the following command at the command prompt:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %a in (Input.txt) do pdftk Input.pdf cat %a output %b
```

to split up the PDF into separate files.

If you simply want to save each page as a separate file, you can use the [*burst*](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-burst) parameter instead. See that man page or type `pdftk --help` for details.