# Split large PDF into smaller Two-page PDFs

Tags: macos, pdf, automator

I have several very large PDF files that I need to split into smaller ones by page number.

For example: In a 100 page long PDF, I want to have one PDF with pages 1-2, one with 3-4, one with 4-5 and so on.. Is this possible to Automate in any way? I need to do this with several documents.

Comment: related: [Splitting a PDF document in two without purchasing a PDF editing tool](http://superuser.com/q/446674/172747) ,  [How to split pdf file in windows?](http://superuser.com/q/684769/172747) ,  [Splitting a PDF into PDFs of various sizes](http://superuser.com/q/565028/172747)

Comment: I believe your question can be answered via [Splitting a PDF into PDFs of various sizes](http://superuser.com/questions/565028/splitting-a-pdf-into-pdfs-of-various-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

You could for example use PDFSam (which should also be available for mac).

`pdfsam -f x.pdf -o . -s NSPLIT -n 2 split` splits the PDF `x.pdf` after every second page.

In terminal `pdfsam` might also be `pdfsam-console`.